# potential leak into escapedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

With this code:

```
NSString *escapedString = (__bridge NSString *)
    CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
    (__bridge CFStringRef)([dictionary objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:i]]),
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

[POSTBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", 
    [keyArray objectAtIndex:i], escapedString] 
    dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I am getting this error:

> potential leak into escapedString

Comment: And also, when I turn ARC on, I get an error of semantic issue in a weak property of @synthesize. If I turn the ARC off, it goes back to the leaking issue. Can anyone show how to fix this?

Comment: Probably need a CFRelease.  But you should use ARC.   What property causes this semantic issue?  Are you sure ARC wasn't telling you to switch *to* weak from retain?

Comment: stevesliva @synthesize property causes the semantic issue.

Comment: It's more code than just synthesize, at what specifically that is matters. Synthesize is fine under ARC, though often unnecessary because you get iVars without it as long as you don't override the accessors.